# External display: After standby, window positions are reset (MacBook Pro clamshell mode)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, big-sur

I'm running macOS Big Sur on a MacBook Pro 15-inch 2017 in clamshell mode with an external display (LG 27UD58). I almost never open the laptop or disconnect it from the display.

After I wake my MacBook from sleep, the windows all gather in the lower-left corner, instead of remembering their previous positions.

Is there a way to fix this?

I thought that maybe there is an LG driver I could install but I couldn't find anything. I've seen similar reports by other users but haven't come across any solution so far.

Thanks for your help!